# SQL query error (NOT IN operator)

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I have this query in SQL

```
SELECT E.ID E.name
into #TmpEmplyee
FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S
WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Student UNION SELECT ID FROM Outsourcing)
```

And I have this exception:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.name FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FRO' at line 1`

I have tried to run the inner query and it works. I think that the problem is with `NOT IN` operator but I don't know where it is. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a join condition between the three tables. I'm pretty sure you do not want a cartesian join between the three.

Comment: This is true, I just assumed he was starting small and was going to work up to a more complicated join. I do that all the time.

Comment: Fields have to be separated, add a comma `,` after `E.ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a comma :-)

```
SELECT E.ID, E.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing comma:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.name
           ^--
```

right now you're trying to define `E.name` as an alias for `E.ID`, but aliases can't have periods in them.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.ID, E.name
into #TmpEmplyee
FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S
WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Student UNION SELECT ID FROM Outsourcing);
```

Commas are important.

Answer (score 1):

you need a comma between query

```
SELECT E.ID,E.name
into #TmpEmplyee
FROM Employee E, Outsourcing O, Student S
WHERE E.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Student UNION SELECT ID FROM Outsourcing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better avoid IN (NOT IN does unexpected things with NULL values, (but since these "key fields" are probably not nullable that won't be a problem here), and avoid UNION (UNION needs to remove duplicates, and thus may need to sort twice)), especially if they are not needed ;-)

NOTE: the query below could "short circuit" (it does not *need* to evaluate both the EXISTSs if one one of them yields True), so it could need to fetch fewer rows in the subqueries than the UNION variant.

```
SELECT E.ID,E.name
-- into #TmpEmplyee
FROM Employee E
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Student s
    WHERE s.ID=E.ID
    )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Outsourcing o
    WHERE o.ID=E.ID
    )
    ;
```